# How to fetch data from MySQL database into nested JSON array using php script?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am able to get data from MySQL to single JSON array using php scripting, But i don't know how to fetch multiple column data from database to nested JSON array. please help me to understand this.

This php code works for fetching data into single JSON array

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$sql ="select * from upcomingevent_banner";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$response = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response,array("image"=>$row[1]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
$conn->close();

?>
```

I want following type of JSON array, What PHP code do i need to use?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Dance",
      "section": [
        {
          "name": "kids dancing in school",
          "image": "http://images1.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Bharatanattyam",
          "image": "http://image2.com
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Music",
      "section": [
        {
          "name": "keyboard player",
          "image": "image3.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "you gotta do that",
          "image": "https://image4.com"
        },

      ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried

Comment: Post your code here not images!!

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so finding some difficulty to paste my code. sorry for that.

Comment: Please post your table structure or a short example of your table. If you have a small table, you can use [Text Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables), but an image if fine too.

Comment: There is no such thing as *"JSON array"*. [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an array or an object). You need to decode the JSON to get back the original data structure and an array or an object is not JSON.

Comment: so how can i get data as above json format using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the appropriate array, then you can use `json_encode()` to turn it into `JSON`. The array to product the sample JSON would be this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
  "data"=>array(
    array(
      "title"=>"Dance",
      "section"=>array(
        array(
          "name"=>"kids dancing in school",
          "image"=>"http://images1.com",
        ),
        array(
          "name"=>"Bharatanattyam",
          "image"=>"http://image2.com",
        ),
      ),
    ),
    array(
      "title"=>"Music",
      "section"=>array(
        array(
          "name"=>"keyboard player",
          "image"=>"image3.com",
        ),
        array(
          "name"=>"you gotta do that",
          "image"=>"http://image4.com",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```

**Note:** You cannot retrieve a multi-level array like this from a single SQL statement. The best you can do is an array of rows with named columns. `section` is an array of two rows with two columns each. `data` is also an array rows with two columns each.

So to get this multi level array, you are going to have to build it manually, but "gimme t codz" is off topic for Stack Overflow. So take a crack at it, and if you have additional trouble, post additional questions with code.

Comment: Thank you jmarkmurphy, Your code gave me idea to solve my issue.